# Zend Form Element Select - how to return integer?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

Is there any way to configure Zend\Form\Element\Select to return integer?
If I have a Form with a Select Element something like this (this is the common way to configure Select Element according to documentation and my internet research):

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'category_id',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Category',
            'value_options' => array(
                '1' => 'Gold',
                '2' => 'Silver',
                '3' => 'Diamond',
                '4' => 'Charm'    
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
    ));
```

I thought If I change value option like this:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'category_id',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Category',
            'value_options' => array(
                1 => 'Gold',
                2 => 'Silver',
                3 => 'Diamond',
                4 => 'Charm'     
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
    ));
```

the integer will be returned but I was wrong. In both cases string is returned. My php code write this form values to a db table where category_id is defined as int.

Comment: Cast value to int with `intval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ZF2 use the [Zend\Filter\Int](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html#int) or [Zend\Filter\ToInt](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html#toint) depending on which version of ZF2 you are using, Zend\Filter\Int became deprecated in ZF2.4.

In your form, assuming you are using the Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface use:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return array(
        'category_id' => array(
            'required' => TRUE,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'Int'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                // Your validators here
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: I think you can remove `required` and `validators` keys, because `Select` automatically sets `required` to `true` and attaches an `InArray` validator.

Comment: Yes I think you are right @gsc, it's just my preference to put them in.